# JMESPath to extract key where values match

Tags: aws-secrets-manager, jmespath

Given source which looks like:

```
{
  "Name": "sandbox-config",
  "VersionList": {
    "version-2": [ "STAGING" ],
    "version-1": [ "CURRENT", "NEXT" ],
    "version-0": [ "ANCIENT" ]
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a jmespath query which would give me:

```
{
  "Name": "sandbox-config",
  "Version": "version-1"
}
```

where `version-1` is the first key where the value array contains "CURRENT".

So, a query like,

```
{ Name:Name, Version:VersionList.*[?@==`CURRENT`] | [] | [0]}
```

gives me:

```
{
  "Name": "sandbox-config",
  "Version": "CURRENT"
}
```

which isn't what I'm after. Similarly:

```
{Name:Name, Version:VersionList.keys(@)}
```

which gives me:

```
{
  "Name": "sandbox-config",
  "Version": [
    "version-2",
    "version-1",
    "version-0"
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions? I feel like I'm circling around a solution and not quite getting there.

(Context for this: I'm trying to process the output of `aws secretsmanager list-secrets`, which has `SecretVersionsToStages` with ARN values as keys with an array containing "AWSCURRENT".)

Comment: One of your requirements ( "... where the first key where the value array contains 'CURRENT'") is a challenge since JSON objects are inherently unordered.  

A JSON text file has an order but the JSON spec, and code processing JSON is not likely to preserve that order. The JMSEPATH explicitly states that it treats a JSON object as "an unordered collection of key-value pairs."

IMPORTANT:  Never assume the order of keys in JSON objects is preserved, if the order is important, use an array.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_DescribeSecret.html#API_DescribeSecret_ResponseSyntax

if you want just get the version number for one secret with stage [AWSCURRENT], I recommend you use describe secret rather than list secret.
And one thing I need to call out is that  SecretVersionsToStages with versoin number as keys with an array containing "AWSCURRENT".